# My TextView behaves strange. I cannot type in the middle of text

Tags: ios, textview

After I write some text in my TextView, like five sentences, the text is saved in CoreData. And after retrieving the data, I continue to write. However, it is so strange. This is because I want to edit some words in the middle of my text but the TextView forces my input at the last of the text. All typed words go to the end of my TextView. Why? Here is the code for my TextView delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)

    navBarSetting()
    textSetting()
    highlight()
    self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
}

func textSetting(){
    myTextView.delegate = self
    myTextView.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular", size: 18.0)
    myTextView.text = showText
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    myTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        self.singleton.addText(text: self.myTextView.text)
        self.myTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    highlightColors(type: allDataBase)
    let maxHeight = 80.0  
    if(myTextView.frame.size.height.native < maxHeight) {
        _ = myTextView.sizeThatFits(myTextView.frame.size)
    }
}

func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle       = UIBarStyle.default
    let flexSpace              = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(TextViewController.doneButtonAction))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.myTextView.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}

func doneButtonAction() {
    self.myTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**Update**

I understood that this problem derives from that I used my `attributedText`. And when a text, where a word is highlighted, is saved, this problem occurs. Without any highlited words saved, there is no problem.

Comment: can you add Screen short or Video?

Comment: have you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()` in `textViewDidBeginEditing` method

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    myTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

i hope it will work

Comment: Yes, but this did not work. Could you check my update please?